# Framework for a site

Tags: php, jquery, django, django-models

I have a project and it needs a framework may be,So the project goes this way the users visit  to the site and if they like they can create a login which gives them extra features to the site.My question is that will Django  suit the requirement or PHP(**Please give me explainations as to why**) Jquery will be in a common candidate for both.

Also how to scale and measure the site in terms of its usage

**Edit:**

I have been using Django and PHP for more than 2-3 years now. I still cannot make up my mind.

In Django coding for example lets say coding has to be done on server side in python and use the template language to render it.

While in PHP serverside/Client side coding can done in PHP itself.

I personally like Django apart from the framework,directory structures, python library -- how different is it from PHP(PHP also has APIS defined in it) .

The only thing i can think about  is that PHP would not define directory structures and its left entirely to the user

While Django manages DB.In PHP user has to write queries/manage DBs

Comment: A framework that supports logging in is hardly ground breaking....

Comment: To track site usage, I'd recommend an analytics package such as Piwik - http://www.piwik.org

Answer (score 4):

Django is a framework. PHP is a language. They are a strange thing to compare :)

Django is an excellent choice as a framework for writing web applications, and can be made to scale very well.

Django will give you authentication and sessions 'for free' as well as templating, eassy caching and many other features Check out the (excellent) [docs](http://www.djangoproject.com/) for more info.

There are PHP frameworks out there for writing web applications, but to be honest I couldn't tell you about any in detail :)

As for measuring, there are many open source options in this area, you might like to look into [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) for a monitoring solution. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare Django (a web framework for the Python programming language) with its analog in the PHP programming language, have a look at [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com), [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/), or [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/). On the Python side, have a look at [Pylons](http://pylonshq.com/) and [web2py](http://web2py.com). Which one you choose is generally a matter of preference, as they all do pretty close to the same sort of thing.

Try to keep in mind that coding solely in PHP can be an exercise in disaster if you're not fully acquainted with how to manage a web application. All of these projects use the Model-View-Controller design pattern, as it's become the leading method of delivering web content in modern web frameworks. Study MVC and learn the basics of all of these frameworks. Only then will you really know what will suit your project best.

Comment: @Rajeev I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what PHP does. PHP and Python basically do the same thing. You can use templating languages in either language and have the same types of design patterns in each. ORMs are by no means exclusive to Python. As I said in my answer, learn about the frameworks I've listed and make the decision for yourself.

Comment: @Rajeev My point is that this comment on your original post *"While Django manages DB.In PHP user has to write queries/manage DBs"* shows that you don't quite realize that Django and PHP aren't analogous. There are frameworks (and ORM libraries) in PHP that manage everything to do with the database, just like Django does. Read up on those frameworks and look up good PHP ORM libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Yii framework is very perspective. Now there is alot of features. MVC also implemented well. Very easy to learn and very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

you cant really compare a language and a framework but if you have the choice drop PHP.

Django/Python has a lot of battery included , it means it is a framework and CMF. Python is clean makes sense and you can write code really fast, without all the php non sense. You'll spend time writing just the things you need and not fix the language shortcomings.

There are good frameworks in php , Symfony for instance , but the tools are just not there.
With python and django you get loads of tools for development ,fabric , south , pip , that makes development a breeze.